# Problem with ASP.NET and IE6,7

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I have two web pages: one consists of four asp.net text boxes and one submit button (main page) and another page which loads data from xml.
The problem is that when i open the second page and click "Back" button in browser to return to the main page 'submit' button ONLY REFRESHES the main page and nothing else happens.
This behavior occurs only in Internet Explorer 6 and 7.
Help me please ))

===============================================================================

As it turned out the problem is that the button click handler does not executes. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your PageLoad look like?  You may want to post some code to clarify.

Comment: i agree you need to post some code - everything up to and including button click event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that first page allows anonymous access and not allows windows authentication but the second page requires windows authentication.

The solution is to allow "window authentication" on the first page.